# Java Date to String without suffix timezone

Tags: java, spring, date, amazon-ec2, timezone

I've created the function below:

```
public static String marshalDate(Calendar value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String format = date.format(value.getTime());
        return format;
    }
}
```

The input will be Calendar, the string value is: `2014-10-17 00:00:00.000000`

The expected result after running the function above should be:

`2014-10-17`

it works properly when I deploy the spring boot application locally and hitting the API on local.

But when deploying the spring boot application on AWS, and I was hitting the API from local, the value that I received is:
`2014-10-17-04:00`

I guess the server was returning the timezone as the suffix.

How can I remove the `-04:00` with function above?

Thank you very much

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you have shown us. I can’t guess where it is then.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Extra plus: its `toString` method gives you the string that you want.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, you're right. But the Calendar is generated by jaxb, so I could not decide which will be used.

Comment: I just saw a new thing, thought it can be the root cause of this problem. There are 2 classes same name and package inside jar. they come from 2 different dependencies. The spring boot has picked the first one that is found to use. someway somehow it picked the class that not containing the method above.

Comment: An interesting observation and a likely cause for the behaviour that you have observed,

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm that the implementation above is correct. The reason for my problem comes from another aspect.
Jaxb has generated 2 classes same name and package inside Jar, and the context will pick the first one that is found to use. As always it was not picking my implementation.